# How to generate a summary of some text

Tags: javascript, html, text, artificial-intelligence

I would like to generate a summary of the input in a textarea. I would like to use AI. This is my HTML:

```
<textarea id="summary">Enter text here</textarea>
```

Please send me your code! Thanks.

Comment: StackOverFlow is not going  to answer your entire Question you need to add some custom searching

Answer (score -3):

Try using QuillBot.

`https://quillbot.com/summarize`

They may have an `api` that you can integrate in your application.